# get eaaccessory macaddress in swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth, eaaccessory

i have a bt 2.0 device with certified.

i can send/recv data with this bt device with eaaccessory input/output stream.

but i went to get the device's mac address

there is a ios9 eaaccessory header

https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/EAAccessory.h

- (id)macAddress;

how can i call this method ??

this app do not need submit to apple store.

Comment: That's a private library. You won't get it allowed to used it if you want to get your app published in the AppStore. In an old version (maybe iOS6) the MAC Address of the device was present in the `description` (but that's clearly not recommended to get it from `description`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get value with:

```
let mac = myAccessory.valueForKey("macAddress")
print("mac address is: \(mac)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `accessory.valueForKey("macAddress")` may work, but you might also find that some manufacturers encode the MAC address in the `accessory.serialNumber` field.

For example, Epson Bluetooth printers' serial numbers are just their MAC addresses without the : separators.